# How to plot multiple scatter plots in the same window with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot 15 scatter plots (5 rows and 3 columns) in the same window, using matplotlib. I've already found a code to solve a problem similar to this, but i can't adapt it to my problem. I think it is easy to do, but I'm having difficult with this. Can someone help me?

This is the code I'm trying to reuse:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w=10
h=10
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
columns = 4
rows = 5
for i in range(1, columns*rows +1):
    img = np.random.randint(10, size=(h,w))
    fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i)
    plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Thank you

Comment: If you just want 3 columns then change the 4 to a 3? The code you posted works as intended.

Comment: I'm having some issues when I zoom the graphic, so I changed the number of columns and rows to test it, but didn't work.

Comment: *How* did it not work? Did you use the code from my answer below?

Comment: Your code is working, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following creates two `numpy` arrays and plots a figure with 15 subplots, arranged in 5 rows and 3 columns. Note that you can dynamically assign your `x` and `y` variables inside of the `for` loop as well, especially if you would like to loop through a set of data while creating each individual subplot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(1,10,10)
y = np.linspace(1,10,10)

fig = plt.figure(1)

columns = 3
rows = 5

for i in range(1, columns*rows+1):
    fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i)
    plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this code is working fine. How can I resize these plots?

Comment: You can use the zoom feature in the lower right corner of the figure window to zoom in on any of the plots manually. If you are intending to change the x and y axis limits, then that can be done inside of the for loop as you create each of the subplots. If I have answered your question, please feel free to click the green check mark to accept my answer, thanks!